# How can I get the line number that a function was called from?

Tags: javascript

```
function eatSoup () {
    // Need line number of where I was called from. [in this case, line 6]
    var lineNumber = answerToThisQuestion();
}

function cookSoup () {
    eatSoup();
}
```

If you need more clarification, just ask.

Comment: Put a breakpoint, follow the stack trace. See here https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: @elclanrs - Not everyone is using Chrome.

Comment: When do you need it? (1)As the script is running so you (the developer) can follow it, (2)As data for the script, (3)Before any code is executed (i.e. static analysis)?

Comment: Firefox https://getfirebug.com/faq/, Opera http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/. My point being, this is about searching a bit if it's about debuggin...

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/3bCDT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `console.trace();` to get full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

```
function cookSoup () {
    debugger;
    eatSoup();
}
```

This will trigger the debugger and you can see the line number from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's not standards compliant, and a bit mangled to one line, but...

```
var calledFromLineNumber = +((new Error).stack.split('\n')[2].split(':')[1]);
```